# I am trying to write a simple asynchronous code in JS, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```js
function order(number) {
  console.log("Queuing order: " + number);
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++); // kill time
  console.log("Order: " + number + " completed");
}

function takeOrder(number, cb) {
  console.log("Preparing order: " + number + "");
}
console.log("Starting to accept order");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("Taking order: " + i);
  takeOrder(i, order(i));
}
console.log("Job completed!");
```

I am trying to make it work as while the order(number) is busy executing, the program continues to display the message "Preparing order: .." and "Taking order: .." 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You probably want to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#Promises)

Comment: Nothing in the above is asynchronous.

Comment: Also note that `takeOrder` doesn't call back its `cb`, because it's already been called. Call it as `takeOrder(number, order)` and add `cb(number)` to it.

Comment: If your order processing involves Ajax calls, you should add that code, as it will influence the correct answer. If on the other hand the processing is pure synchronous JavaScript code, why does it take so long to finish?

Comment: @trincot no Ajax calls, its only this. And yes, thanks a lot, because I am new to JS and this asynchronous programming is biting me a lot so I really needed help and guide.

Comment: Can you explain what the sense is in the killing time part? Does your actual code have something meaningful there?

Comment: @trincot no Sir, nothing meaningful, I was just trying to not use setTimeout() and write something of my own to make that function keep on executing and see while it is busy doing that task, can I make the program do other tasks and that when order() is done executing how does the code behaves. Like I said, I am new to js and I am having difficulty in digesting the async programming part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to write a simple asynchronous code in JS...

Nothing in your code is asynchronous. Also, in this code

```
takeOrder(i, order(i));
```

you're **calling** `order` and passing in `i`, then passing its return value (`undefined`) into `takeOrder`. To pass `order` into `takeOrder` instead, remove the `(i)`:

```
takeOrder(i, order);
```

> I am trying to make it work as while the order(number) is busy executing, the program continues to display the message "Preparing order: .." and "Taking order: .."

JavaScript on browsers is run on a single main thread with access to the UI, and then zero or more [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) threads that you create. If the `for` loop in your code is running on the main UI thread, nothing else can happen while it's running, because of JavaScripts run-to-completion semantics.

If the work represented by the `for` loop is **a**synchronous, you don't have to do anything, it's just that your simulation using a `for` loop wasn't an accurate model of your real work. For instance, if it's doing an ajax request.

If the work represented by the `for` loop is completely synchronous like your `for` loop is, I'd probably offload that `for` loop to a web worker:

`worker.js`:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if (e.data && e.data.command == "go") {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++); // kill time
    self.postMessage({command: "log", message: "Order: " + e.data.order + " completed"});
  }
});
```

Your main JS file:

```
function order(number) {
  var w = new Worker("worker.js");
  w.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (e.data && e.data.command == "log") {
      console.log(e.data.message);
    }
    w = null;
  });
  console.log("Queuing order: " + number);
  w.postMessage({command: "go", order: number});
}

function takeOrder(number, cb) {
  console.log("Preparing order: " + number + "");
  cb(number);                                       // Call the callback
}
console.log("Starting to accept order");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("Taking order: " + i);
  takeOrder(i, order);                              // Pass order as the callback
}
console.log("Job completed!");
```

That creates a new worker for each order, so they can overlap.

Output:

```
Starting to accept order
Taking order: 0
Preparing order: 0
Queuing order: 0
Taking order: 1
Preparing order: 1
Queuing order: 1
Taking order: 2
Preparing order: 2
Queuing order: 2
Job completed!
Order: 0 completed
Order: 1 completed
Order: 2 completed
```

Note how the main thread tells the worker to start via a message, and the worker communicates completion back to the main thread via a message.

---

Enhancements you could make:

- `order` could return a `Promise` that's fulfilled when the worker finishes its work.
- You could wait to post the "Job completed" until all the order promises had completed.
- The worker could post interim updates on its progress back to the main thread.
- Obviously, you could include more meaningful information in the messages between the worker threads and the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of web-worker did the job, and I was able to come up with equivalent node.js script

```js
const Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var myWorker = new Worker(function() {
  onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Received order " + event.data.orderNumber + " and it is being processed");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100000000; i++); // processing time.
    postMessage("Order " + event.data.orderNumber + " has been successfully processed");
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("Taking order number: " + i);
  myWorker.postMessage({
    orderNumber: i
  });
  myWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
  }
}
console.log("Completed accepting orders!");
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Taking order number: 0
Taking order number: 1
Received order 0 and it is being processed
Taking order number: 2
Completed accepting orders!
Received order 1 and it is being processed
Received order 2 and it is being processed
Order 0 has been successfully processed
Order 1 has been successfully processed
Order 2 has been successfully processed
```