# How to run multiple asynchronous functions separately without order in JavaScript without interfering with each other?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, polymer, client-side-scripting, polymer-1.x

I want to know if it is possible and how can I run multiple JavaScript functions separately at the sometime without order in Client-Side.

If not possible is there a workaround for it?

Comment: First there is only one thread for javascript in the browser.  So you could use setTimeout to execute multiple function but they will run in round robin way; one after the other.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin: One *main* thread (and as many web workers as you want).

Comment: So is it possible to run functions using web workers?

Comment: *"...without interfering with each other"* You'll need to get a lot more specific about that. What kind of interference are you concerned about? There will be no data races, but since they're async and without order, they can manipulate shared data in an unpredictable order.

Comment: The thing is that I have iron-ajax in Polymer google web framework that calls the handler each time it gets the request and I have sendRequest run inside `this.async()`, the other function is using a web worker.

Comment: Yes Web worker will be executed simultaneously (and can do AJAX), but you don't have access to the DOM and you don't share the same environment (the same variables).  You can communicate between these thread or with the main thread through postMessage.

Comment: The whole meaning of *asynchronous* is that something else can run separately.

Comment: @0x01Brain Please post the code of that and what your problem with it is.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited my post and added my code, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

If you just mean you want to *schedule* them to run in any order, that's fine, just do so (with `setTimeout` or whatever). If they're doing things like waiting on ajax completions and such, they won't interfere with each other. If they're doing work *in the JavaScript code*, though, they'll keep the main UI thread busy when they do actually run.

If you need to do heavy JavaScript processing and want to keep the main UI thread available so the UI is responsive, you can offload the processing to [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which run on a separate thread from the main UI thread, concurrently.

Here's a simple web worker example (from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39424056/157247)):

The main JS file:

```
function order(number) {
  var w = new Worker("worker.js");
  w.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (e.data && e.data.command == "log") {
      console.log(e.data.message);
    }
    w = null;
  });
  console.log("Queuing order: " + number);
  w.postMessage({command: "go", order: number});
}

function takeOrder(number, cb) {
  console.log("Preparing order: " + number + "");
  cb(number);                                       // Call the callback
}
console.log("Starting to accept order");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("Taking order: " + i);
  takeOrder(i, order);                              // Pass order as the callback
}
console.log("Job completed!");
```

`worker.js`:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if (e.data && e.data.command == "go") {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++); // kill time
    self.postMessage({command: "log", message: "Order: " + e.data.order + " completed"});
  }
});
```